# multiplying a string by an integer returns integers?

Tags: string, d

So I was trying to make an asterisk pyramid using D.
First of all I noticed that concatenation seems to be impossible. Writing out something like `writeln("foo" + "bar")` will give you a syntax error. So instead I tried multiplying the strings like in python, that didn't work with double quoted strings, but with single quoted strings something weird happens.

If you type in this

```
import std.stdio;
void main()
{
    foreach (i; 0 .. 10)
    {
        writeln(i*'0');
    }
}
```

it will return a bunch of integers.
Could anyone explain why this happens?
And letting me know how to concatenate strings will also be really helpful.

thanks!

Comment: `+` should never have been used as a concatenation operator. Ever. In **any** language. http://gwydir.demon.co.uk/jo/javascript/numbers.htm#types

Comment: The concatenation operator in D is ~ isntead of +. So try `writeln("foo" ~ "bar");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The '0' is not a string, it is a character, which uses ASCII encoding. The number is being multiplied with the encoding's integer id. For example, the encoding for ASCII's 'A' is 65.

```
import std.stdio;
int main()
{
        writeln( cast(int)'A' );
        writeln( 10 * 'A' );
        return 0;
}
```

This program will print 65 and 650 because the character is being converted to an integer in both cases.

To solve the original concatenation problem you can use the '~' operator for concatenating two arrays, or use "array1 ~= array2" to append array2 onto array1 in one statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Do you think you could help me out with concatenation as well?

Answer (score 2):

First solution that comes to mind:

```
char[5] arr3 = 's';
writeln(arr3);
```

Two alternatives are std.array.replicate and std.range.repeat:

```
import std.array;
import std.stdio;

void main() {
    auto arr = replicate(['s'], 5); // lazy version: http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html#repeat
    // or
    auto arr2 = ['s'].replicate(5);
    writeln(arr);
    writeln(arr2);
}
```